# Can I reuse Value Objects?

Tags: domain-driven-design

According to Domain-Driven Design, can I import and reuse common Value Objects like Email, SocialSecurityNumber, Currency, etc. from external sources?

It seems it would be bad because I'm relying on external code in the heart of my Domain, but for the other side, it seems I would be reinventing the wheel by rewritten the same code over and over again.

Comment: Inheritance is an excellent way to get code reuse without having to reuse domain concepts. So, you could have an Email object outside your domain, but create a meaningful subclass within it -- such as UsersEmailAddress.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Well... generic stuff like Email, SSN can be imported and reused. Basically, the problem with imported stuff is that they might mean something else in their original bounded context. For example, Currency might not be what you need for your Domain. But things like email are generic enough not to matter.

**tldr;** It's ok to reuse generic concepts as long as they are generic enough that they mean the same thing in your Domain.

P.S: You can reuse them even more in validating input i.e outside the domain.

Answer (score 1):

I think It is best to use your own value objects; implemented in a common library.

Then in your value objects you can dispatch validation and rule checks to the externals resources you mentioned; intead of doing it yourself.

Even you can add your own validation rules above them. For example you can put an email rule that prohibits emails from common email providers like gmail, hotmail etc. in a class named "CompanyEmail".